# What does majorization mean in the context of intervals?

Tags: convex-analysis

I just got this book on convex optimization, and in the preliminary section they show syntax for "majorized" and "minorized" intervals as

[image: majorization?]

I searched the terms majorized and minorized within math.stackexchange and elsewhere on the internet, but could not find anything related to intervals.

The closest comes from wikipedia:

> For a vector $ \mathbf {a} \in \mathbb {R} ^{d}$ we denote by $ \mathbf {a} ^{\downarrow }\in \mathbb {R} ^{d} $ the vector with the same components, but sorted in descending order.  Given $ \mathbf {a} ,\mathbf {b} \in \mathbb {R} ^{d} $, we say that $ \mathbf {a} $ weakly majorizes (or dominates) $ \mathbf {b} $ from below written as $ \mathbf {a} \succ _{w}\mathbf {b} $ iff
>
> $ \sum _{i=1}^{k}a_{i}^{\downarrow }\geq \sum _{i=1}^{k}b_{i}^{\downarrow }\quad {\text{for }}k=1,\dots ,d $

But I still have two questions:

1. The order of a sequence doesn't affect its sum, so why is it significant to use the *ordered* vectors $ \mathbf{a}^{\downarrow} $ and $
       \mathbf{b}^{\downarrow} $ within the sums?
2. How does that inequality relate to intervals?

Comment: I'm not sure about "marjorized" and "minorized" but as for the brakets, it's just a less-common notation than using parenthesis. That is, $[a,b)=[a,b[$, and similarly $(a,b]=]a,b]$ and $(a,b)=]a,b[$.

Personally I think this looks horrendous. EDIT: Gae makes a good point, although I still think it looks horrendous.

Comment: On the other hand, some think that $(a,b)$ looks like the pair, hence the $]a,b[$ notation.

Comment: I find the reversed brackets deeply jarring as well.  It's not just foreign - like a piece of newly introduced syntax - it's unsettling like an optical illusion that breaks my parsing of the surrounding expression.  I've been heavily conditioned to treat brackets as directional symbols, such that "[" does not affect anything to the left, and "]" does not affect anything to the right.

Comment: (I should be clear - I understand the brackets.  It's the concepts of majorization and minorization that are unclear to me, especially as applied to intervals.)